# Can I use medium weight white shade cloth as a weed barrier under gravel, under my deck?

Tags: weed-control, shade, gravel, shade-cloth, weedmat

Can I use medium weight white shade cloth as a weed barrier under gravel, under my deck?  I have a ton of it in a very wide roll.

The white shade cloth appears to be more tightly woven and heavier weight than the heavyweight black weed cloth from our hardware store. Once wet, it seems to let water pass just a little slower than the weed cloth.

I will be putting 3" of gravel on top of the cloth, and the ground has been slightly sloped away from the house.  The deck edge around the barrier and gravel will be skirted.

Thanks for any opinions.

Comment: What material is the shade cloth made of?

Comment: I doubt you will need it for weed control; the only growth I see under my deck is vines like Virginia Creeper-with no leaves. They come in from the edges. But the cloth could prevent erosion , which I do have with my sandy soil.